# using str.contains() in python, when it matches string perfectly and still not getting output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using str.contains() for searching movie name from my dataframe and getting no output, but when I have partial string it is giving output correctly. What i want is how to make this code snippet work correctly for both partial and full string matching.

using contains on **partial string**, if I use only '(Volume 1)' in minList i get correct output or the one shown below

```
minList = ['Star Wars: Clone Wars']
for k in minList:
    print(df[df.name.str.contains(k,case=False,na=False)]["name"])
```

> 3208    Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)
> Name: name, dtype: object

using contains on **full string**

```
minList = ['Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)']
for k in minList:
    print(df[df.name.str.contains(k,case=False,na=False)]["name"])
```

and no output

> Series([], Name: name, dtype: object)

tried using query as well()

```
minList = ['Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)']
for k in minList:
    print(df.query('name.str.contains("' + k + '")',engine='python')['name'])
```

But no output

> Series([], Name: name, dtype: object)

Comment: Post the full definition of your dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried adding `regex=False` to the `str.contains()` call ?   `str.contains()` takes  the first parameter as regex by default.  So parenthesis is treated as regex symbols and does not match parenthesis literarlly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an argument `regex=False` to to the `str.contains()` call.

`str.contains()` takes the first parameter as regex (regular expression) by default. So parenthesis is treated as regex symbols and does not match parenthesis literally.

### Demo

```
data = {'name': ['Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)', 'Other strings']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Output:
                               name
0  Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)
1                     Other strings

minList = ['Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)']
for k in minList:
    print(df[df.name.str.contains(k,case=False,na=False, regex=False)]["name"])

Output:   # String extracted successully.

0    Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)
Name: name, dtype: object
```

If you want to match the string with `regex=True`, you need to modify the string passed as first parameter to:

```
minList = [r'Star Wars: Clone Wars \(Volume 1\)']
```

### Demo

```
minList = [r'Star Wars: Clone Wars \(Volume 1\)']
for k in minList:
    print(df[df.name.str.contains(k,case=False,na=False)]["name"])

Output:       # String matched successfully

0    Star Wars: Clone Wars (Volume 1)
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Here we use `\(` instead of just `(` and `\)` instead of just `)`.  We also used raw string `r'....'` to quote the whole string so that we don't need to use double slash for the string which is regarded as regex.